# Angular2 router-deprecated dependencies not being loaded

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have recently updated my angular2 version and have had the following issue:

1. The router lib no longer exists, it has been replaced by router-deprecated.
2. I have this menu component:

   ```
   import { Component }       from '@angular/core';
   import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component'
   import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

   @Component({
     selector: 'main-menu',
     templateUrl: 'app/views/menu.html',
     directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
     providers: [
       ROUTER_PROVIDERS
     ]
   })

   @RouteConfig([
     {
       path: '/dashboard',
       name: 'Dashboard',
       component: DashboardComponent,
       useAsDefault: true
     }
   ])

   export class MenuComponent {}
   ```
3. The app fails when I try to even load it, as it is unable to resolve the files needed from the router-deprecated. I get the following error:

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFfHa.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Angular2 RC.0 you might need to add

```
'@angular/router-deprecated': {
  main: 'index.js',
  defaultExtension: 'js'
},
```

to your `packages` in `config.js`

or this if you want to use the new router:

```
'@angular/router': {
  main: 'index.js',
  defaultExtension: 'js'
},
```

Example `config.js` from the `rc.0` Plunker

```
(function(global) {

  var ngVer = '@2.0.0-rc.0'; // lock in the angular package version; do not let it float to current!

  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var  map = {
    'app':                        'src', // 'dist',
    'rxjs':                       'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'https://npmcdn.com/angular2-in-memory-web-api' // get latest
  };

  //packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'app.ts',  defaultExtension: 'ts' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };

  var packageNames = [
      '@angular/common',
      '@angular/compiler',
      '@angular/core',
      '@angular/http',
      '@angular/platform-browser',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
      '@angular/router-deprecated',
      '@angular/testing',
      '@angular/upgrade',
  ];

  // add map entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': 'https://npmcdn.com/@angular/common@0.0.0-3'
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    map[pkgName] = 'https://npmcdn.com/' + pkgName + ngVer;
  });

  // add package entries for angular packages in the form '@angular/common': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
  packageNames.forEach(function(pkgName) {
    packages[pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  });

  var config = {
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: {
      emitDecoratorMetadata: true
    },
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  }

  // filterSystemConfig - index.html's chance to modify config before we register it.
  if (global.filterSystemConfig) { global.filterSystemConfig(config); }

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

Comment: Greetings,

First I added your first solution but it yielded me new errors. I believe it is better to switch to the new router asap anyway.

I installed the new router and I don't know how it works.

Could you please link me a tutorial/api for the new router?
Thanks! :)

Comment: I haven't found any myself yet. Here are a few bits https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/602641d Here is a Plunker I'm currently playing with https://plnkr.co/edit/yRKhoOelf2uJ3yAsdIMm?p=info

Comment: I viewed your plunker. It seems that the @Router decorater breaks both my IDE and doesn't compile. Do I need to update my ts compiler or something?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: There is no `@Router` decorator. Do you mean `@Routes()`?

Comment: I only experimented in the Plunker so far. Locally I use Dart and don't know too much about configuring a TS environment.

Comment: I see. Well the plunker snippets work, congrats :). 

I use Microsoft code & the standard tsconfig.json, typings.json provided by the angular2 basic site.

Meh, this will probably take some time until they update the docs or something.

Comment: I got everything working now. Had some issues with my ide, and ofc I made some mistakes.

Thank you very much, once again!

Comment: I don't see an official docs about the new router, the docs still use router-deprecated at time of writing.

Comment: I just started angular 2 tutorials with VS Code and I'm facing the same problem, Namik, can you please explain how do I fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

More exactly, with typescript project, add the module dependency in the `package.json` file:

```
dependencies{
    ...
   "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1"
}
```

And in your `src/system-config.ts` file this line:

```
const barrels:string[] = [
     ...
    '@angular/router-deprecated'
];
```

Then, don't forget to run `npm i` in your project to install this module before to use it.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the solution is very simple,
we need to change the systemjs.config.js file.
the packages array holds list of angular packages while one of them is wrong

replace this: '@angular/router',
with this: '@angular/router-deprecated',

```
    systemjs.config.js:
...
...
...

        var packageNames = [
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/compiler',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/router-deprecated',
            '@angular/testing',
            '@angular/upgrade',
          ];
```

that's it.