# angular2.0.0-beta.17 modules not found

Tags: angular

When importing modules in the newest version of Angular2, the module names have been updated.  For instance `angular2/core` became `@angular/core`.  However, whenever I try to use the new modules, my TypeScript compiler throws an error that it cannot find the module.  Anyone else running into this problem?

Comment: Might be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000243/angular2-router-deprecated-dependencies-not-being-loaded You need to update your config.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@angular/* are for angular2.0.0-rc.0 and greater.

See the changelog at: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Ah ok, thanks.  I thought it was for the latest beta version.  I can't seem to find a way to view the old beta API on their website.

Comment: I guess they wouldn't even have the beta documentation since they have an RC. :)