# Router errors after upgrading to Angular 2 RC

Tags: angular

```
app/main-menu.component.ts(18,24): error TS2339: Property 'isRouteActive' does not exist on type 'Router'.
app/main-menu.component.ts(18,50): error TS2339: Property 'generate' does not exist on type 'Router'.
```

My main-menu component:

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from '@angular/router';

...
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],

export class MainMenuComponent {    

        constructor(private router: Router, private JwtService:JwtService){}

public isRouteActive(route) {
    return this.router.isRouteActive(this.router.generate(route))
}

}
```

I checked the angular 2 router docs and everything is still same, so why do I get this errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the new router with the "old" code.

Change

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from '@angular/router';
```

to

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
```

See also [Angular2 router-deprecated dependencies not being loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000243/angular2-router-deprecated-dependencies-not-being-loaded/37000268#37000268)

Comment: Hmh, I think using a depreacted version of router is a bad idea, Wouldn't be better to use the new one with a new code? I just have no idea where to find the new methods of `isRouteActive` and `router.generate`

Comment: Sure but you might do it in steps. At first upgrade to `rc.1` and when this is done, migrate to the new router. The new router has quite a few issues, therefore you might wait another release until fully migrating your code. They were just quite eager to get it out as RC before ng-conf. It can be used for experimenting and learning already of course.