# How to fix Angular 2 `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null`?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I've been using the Heroes tutorial in the Angular 2 docs to experiment. However, I've come to a point that I don't understand what's happening with this error:

`Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null` in `browser_adapter.ts:88`.

The two pieces involved are the `HeroDetailComponent` and the `HeroService`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
import { RouteParams } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import { Hero, HeroService } from '../index';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-hero-detail',
    templateUrl: ...
    styleUrls: [...]
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {

    hero: Hero;

    // TEMPORARY FIX:
    _heroService = new HeroService();  // Avoids injection

    // constructor(private _heroService: HeroService,
    //             private _routeParams: RouteParams) {}

    constructor(private _routeParams: RouteParams) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        let id = +this._routeParams.get('id');
        console.log(id);
    }
}
```

When the I use this code, it works. But when I switch the constructors, and use the one with the `HeroService` injection, then I get the error I mentioned earlier.

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

    getHeroes() {
        return HEROES;
    }

    getHero(id: number) {
        return new Hero(1, 'Name', 'Power', 'AlterEgo');
    }
}
```

While I was trying to figure out what's going on I removed all the promise-related code. However, I still get the same error. Everything is compiling fine, it's a runtime error. The `HeroService` and `RouteParams` are provided in a parent component.

Two questions:

1. How to solve this issue?
2. How to debug this kind of problems?

I'm inclined to think it's a bug in Angular 2, but I'm not sure how make sure that it's not an error on my part. Thanks in advance.

UPDATES:

1. I've added the the temporary fix code (which avoids injection and thus is not a solution to this question as I would like to have injection working properly).
2. [This is a Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nnqS3x2jbScZG0zd8CXI?p=preview) with an approximate version of the code I'm trying. I couldn't get it to run properly, but it may be helpful to diagnose the problem by looking into the code.

Comment: You don't seem to be providing the ``HeroService``. Is it provided in a parent component?

Comment: Yes, it's provided in a parent component. Thanks. I'll add it to the question description.

Comment: Ah, maybe a plunkr that reproduces this is in order.

Comment: I assume an import `HeroService` or `RouteParams` is missing. What Angular2 version are you using? If you use rc.x see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000243/angular2-router-deprecated-dependencies-not-being-loaded

Comment: I've been trying to create a Plunker, but I haven't been able to make it work correctly, but you may get the idea so I'm putting it in the question. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Both `HeroService` and `RouteParams` are imported in the file an injected in a component higher up the chain @GünterZöchbauer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see the following problem: `HeroComponent` depends on `HeroDetailsComponent`, but `HeroDetailsComponent` is exported **afterwards** in the `app/heroes/index.ts` file.

Someone reported a problem with this kind of set up [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8573)

Comment: Thanks! This fixed the problem for me. It never crossed my mind that this could be the cause of the problem. I probably need to study more on the internals for JavaScript.

Comment: I spent many hours trying to find this. We're all learning!
Right now I spend a lot of time navigating Github issues because I'm trying out many beta products (angular2, .net core, bootstrap4, etc.). Really worth searching there when you're stuck.

Answer (score 3):

In the "tsconfig.json" set "emitDecoratorMetadata" parameter of the "compilerOptions" section to the "true" value.

Comment: The `emitDecoratorMetadata` is already set to `true`. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error with angular RC1 when I was injecting `FormBuilder` inside the constructor like this:

```
export class App {
  constructor(public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}
}
```

But I didn't `import` it previously!
Just add it solves the problem:

`import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/common'`

Comment: Thanks. However, the import statement is there (see the code in the question).

Answer (score 0):

Try with these compilerOptions in "tsconfig.json". It worked for me (Version 2.0.0-rc.1 of angular).

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true   },
```

I had the same problem with injectables (same error) and the fix did the trick for services but not for http. I modified my options based on a tutorial from ng-book2 and it finally worked.

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer.

Comment: The only thing different between those settings and mine was the `"noLib": false` and `"declaration: false"`, but it didn't solve the problem for me. Thanks anyways @GizmoW.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I fix this problem using `@Inject` decorator. Try this:

```
import {Inject} from '@angular/core'

constructor(@Inject(HeroService) private _heroService: HeroService,
            @Inject(RouteParams) private _routeParams: RouteParams) {}
```

My project is configured with JSPM and this is the only way to work with dependency injection, I do not why, anyone has an explanation?

Edited: I have found the solution. In my case, I have to add this configuration into config.js file

```
System.config({
 baseURL: "",
 defaultJSExtensions: true,
 transpiler: "typescript",
 typescriptOptions: {
    "target": "es5",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
 },
 paths: {
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*",
 ....
```

Now I can remove @Inject decorator and this sentence works properly

```
constructor(private _heroService: HeroService,
            private _routeParams: RouteParams) {}
```

The key is `emitDecoratorMetadata: true`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. Decorator metadata was already being emitted and other part with injection work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer as of RC1 is to add the `@Inject(Service) private service:Service` wherever you are injecting services.

This caused me no end of headache after I upgraded on Monday to RC1.

Comment: `@Inject()` should not be necessary when the parameter to `@Inject(...)` is the same as the type for the parameter. The root cause seems to be something else.