# Weird can't access 'query' of null error

Tags: typescript, angular

What's this error for? Could benefit from a more descriptive error, but this had me lost. It has no reference to anything i've done, and it just happens. The code was working in Angular2 beta.9 but after upgrading to rc1 this is started to happen. No extensions to Angular2 or anything crazy in the solution, just a component:

**Component**

```
import {Component, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'login-form',
    templateUrl: '/Home/Login.html'  
})
export class Login {        
    constructor(elm: ElementRef) { } 
}
```

Also all angular files are loaded properly. This is the stack trace of the error:

```
browser_adapter.ts:78 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null
BrowserDomAdapter.logError 
@ browser_adapter.ts:78 BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup 
@ browser_adapter.ts:89 ExceptionHandler.call 
@ exception_handler.ts:53(anonymous function) 
@ application_ref.ts:304 schedulerFn 
@ async.ts:131 SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub 
@ Subscriber.ts:240 SafeSubscriber.next 
@ Subscriber.ts:192 Subscriber._next 
@ Subscriber.ts:133 Subscriber.next 
@ Subscriber.ts:93 Subject._finalNext 
@ Subject.ts:154 Subject._next 
@ Subject.ts:144Subject.next 
@ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit 
@ async.ts:117NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError 
@ ng_zone.ts:138NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError 
@ ng_zone_impl.ts:90ZoneDelegate.handleError 
@ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded 
@ zone.js:233_loop_1 
@ zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue 
@ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke 
@ zone.js:426 browser_adapter.ts:78STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError 
@ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call 
@ exception_handler.ts:56(anonymous function) 
@ application_ref.ts:304schedulerFn 
@ async.ts:131SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub 
@ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next
@ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next 
@ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next 
@ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext 
@ Subject.ts:154Subject._next 
@ Subject.ts:144Subject.next 
@ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit 
@ async.ts:117NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError 
@ ng_zone.ts:138NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError 
@ ng_zone_impl.ts:90ZoneDelegate.handleError 
@ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded 
@ zone.js:233_loop_1 
@ zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue 
@ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke 
@ zone.js:426
browser_adapter.ts:78Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:538)
    at PromiseCompleter.reject (zone.js:515)
    at eval (application_ref.ts:340)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:323)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (ng_zone_impl.ts:67)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:322)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:216)
    at zone.js:571
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:356)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (ng_zone_impl.ts:56)BrowserDomAdapter.logError 
@ browser_adapter.ts:78ExceptionHandler.call 
@ exception_handler.ts:57(anonymous function) 
@ application_ref.ts:304schedulerFn 
@ async.ts:131SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub 
@ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next 
@ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next 
@ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next 
@ Subscriber.ts:93Subject._finalNext 
@ Subject.ts:154Subject._next 
@ Subject.ts:144Subject.next 
@ Subject.ts:90EventEmitter.emit 
@ async.ts:117NgZone._zoneImpl.ng_zone_impl_1.NgZoneImpl.onError 
@ ng_zone.ts:138NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onHandleError 
@ ng_zone_impl.ts:90ZoneDelegate.handleError 
@ zone.js:327Zone.runGuarded 
@ zone.js:233_loop_1 
@ zone.js:487drainMicroTaskQueue 
@ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke 
@ zone.js:426
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'query' of null ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null(…)consoleError 
@ zone.js:461_loop_1 
@ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue 
@ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke 
@ zone.js:426
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null(…)
```

**Update**

This is the configuration:

```
  <script src="/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            System.config({
                defaultJSExtensions: true,
                baseURL: 'lib/src/scripts',
                map: {
                    '@angular/common': '../../node_modules/@angular/common/index',
                    '@angular/core': '../../node_modules/@angular/core/index',
                    '@angular/compiler': '../../node_modules/@angular/compiler/index',
                    '@angular/http': '../../node_modules/@angular/http/index',
                    '@angular/platform-browser': '../../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/index',
                    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': '../../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index',
                    '@angular/router': '../../node_modules/@angular/router/index',
                    'rxjs': '../../node_modules/rxjs'
                }
            });
    </script>
```

Comment: Does the error go away if you remove the `elm:ElementRef` constructor parameter?

Comment: woa! yes it does. HOW? I've used `ElementRef` before, never this happened.

Comment: I guess there isn't much you can do wrong with the `ElementRef` import. I guess there is something wrong with your configuration. The error indicates a problem with DI resolving or passing a dependency (don't know exactly but the error was always related to DI)

Comment: Is there any specific provider setup before using `ElementRef`?

Comment: Ok then why would the DI not work in this case? seems a rather straight forward, done it before, solution.

Comment: This is why I think it's an issue with the configuration but I can't help you here. I'm not using TS (only Dart)

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/tyn4dgRm2VThmAOttK49?p=preview

Comment: Possibly the same issue as this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105614/how-to-fix-angular-2-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-property-qu I'm still struggling to find a fix, none of the answers so far here and in the other post have worked.

Comment: @Harry it's the same issue. It was fixed after changing CommonJS to SystemJS on `module` element in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: @Hani thanks, unfortunately that change still hasn't fixed things for me. I'll keep looking.

Comment: @Harry welcome to beta programming! I would've still used knockout if it was my choice since ASP.NET takes care of most things for me. All really needed was organizing client-side code and behaviors.

Comment: @Hani :P what's very annoying actually is that this is supposed to be a "Release Candidate" and as far as I can tell more things are broken than the last beta, and they switched in a new, undocumented, and untested router that everyone is struggling with. I don't have a problem with using a beta, just don't pretend it's an RC!

Comment: @Harry I think i mentioned somewhere in SO that i fell back to beta.15 for now. Bundling is an issue as well, couldn't figure out all the RC1 files, with that `index` added to the mix, and how to bundle them.

Comment: @Hani I'm back on beta.17 with few issues. I'd recommend JSPM for bundling (RC or beta), I've found it a lot more straightforward to use than Webpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your typescript configuration matches your module configuration (aka modules 101). Issue was that original module setup was done as `SystemJS` but `module`option was set to 'commonjs' in `tsconfig.json`. No wonder it was too crazy to be true, although 'SystemJS' supposed to pollyfill for 'commonjs' and it had, there was still this crazy error.

**Update**

Change your `tsconfig.json` file to look like this:

```
//if planning to build a release bundle, remember to use the following on top of every .ts file if using this configuration.
//use /// <amd-module name="your .ts file path from site root" /> for a named system.register (module: "system") or define (module: "amd")
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es3" //or es5, es6 if you can
  }
}
```

Additionally, you might also want to exclude `node_modules` and `typings`, I didn't need to:

```
...
exclude: ["node_modules", "typings"]
...
```

A trick here was not to use `commonjs` as the value `module`, so you can use `amd` or `system`. In my case, due to release build process with `systemjs-builder`, I chose `amd` in order not to include any module loaders.

Following is `systemjs` configuration which I used for DEV environment only:

```
System.config({
    defaultJSExtensions: true,
    baseURL: '/',
    map: {
        '@angular/common': 'node_modules/@angular/common/index',
        '@angular/core': 'node_modules/@angular/core/index',
        '@angular/compiler': 'node_modules/@angular/compiler/index',
        '@angular/http': 'node_modules/@angular/http/index',
        '@angular/platform-browser': 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/index',
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index',
        '@angular/router': 'node_modules/@angular/router/index',
        'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm just a beginner here, so when you say "original module setup", where was that set up ?

Comment: I was referring to Angular2 setup. If you've seen their tutorials, they setup SystemJS scripts to run in browser. Issue here was that typescript was transpiling CommonJS. I never figured out why the error was happening, specially since SystemJS does pollyfill for CommonJS.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I solved this issue by setting typescript option `--emitDecoratorMetadata`, hope it will help some people.

Comment: In Visual Studio, your solution won't build. If you don't have that configuration TSC will complain about it.