# Why can I not access my local variable in my ngAfterViewInit function?

Tags: angular, typescript

Any recommendations on why this is not working, and/or how this could be done better is greatly appreciated.

**Situational Summary:**
I have a SelectionComponent that is created based on a NavComponent selection. When a user makes their selection, and the Selectioncomponent is created, there is an export class that implements ngOnInit to fetch data from a service based on the index of the selected component (this works fine). I also wanted to populate the SelectionComponent's html template with other data from another service that depends upon the user's selection. However, the second service depends on a local variable in SelectionComponent's export class in order to filter the correct metadata from the database. That local variable is not defined either by scope or when this tries to reference it, and that is the error that is breaking the app I think??

**What I have tried:**
 - I tried adding the getLocation call in ngOnInit also, but the local
   variable is undefined at this time.
      - I tried using ngAfterViewInit to call the getLocation function after ngOnInit, but the local variable was still undefined.
   -  I did not add    the @ViewChild like mentioned in:    http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/.

**The code causing my problem:**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

import {SelectionService}...;
import {Selection}...;
import {LocationService}...;
import {Location}...;

@Component({
    selector: 'selection',
    templateUrl: 'selection.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['selection.component.css']
})

export class SelectionComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {


    selection: Selection;
    locations: Locations[] = [];


    constructor(private selectionService: SelectionService,
                private locationService: LocationService,
                private route: ActivatedRoute) {}


    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params
            .switchMap((params: Params) => this.seletionService.getSelectionByName(params['name']))
            .subscribe(selection=> this.selection = selection);
    }

    getLocationsBySelection(id: number): void {
        this.locationService.getLocationsBySelection(id).then(locations => this.locations = locations);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.getLocationsBySelection(this.selection.id);
    }


}
```

**The component's html in brief:**

```
<div *ngIf="selection">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- boiler plate html -->
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="locations.length < 0" class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <h5 class="grey-text center-align">Locations</h5>
            </div>
            <div *ngFor="let location of locations" class="col s12 m4">
                <!-- more boilerplate content with a dash of angular interpolation -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Error message**
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

**Resources**
I have read through all of Angular's Tour of Hero examples on their site, and some related questions like this: [How to fix Angular 2 `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37105614/how-to-fix-angular-2-uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-property-qu). They do not really do this type of thing in those examples. As listed prior,http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/, discussed an example that seemed to be very close to the situation I am facing but I do not intend to load another component, just perform another query for data based on the current selection.

Comment: Check first, did u get `this.selection.id` or not?

Comment: You are trying to use a value that you get in the callback of an async function in another async function..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to call `getLocationsBySelection` inside your `ngOnInit` after you get all details of `selection` from `getSelectionByName` service call  and you can remove `ngAfterViewInit`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.params.switchMap((params: Params) => this.seletionService.getSelectionByName(params['name']))
      .subscribe(selection=> { 
        this.selection = selection;
        if (typeof this.selection.id !== 'undefined') {
          this.getLocationsBySelection(this.selection.id);
        }
      })
}
```