# router deprecated is not found in angular 2 package

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Recently i ran  **npm install** command in my angular2 project directory, but it didn't install **router-deprecated** under my angular package.

Has it been omitted from recent release?

If yes, where can i find **RouterOutlet** class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it in your config

```
'@angular/router-deprecated': {
  main: 'router-deprecated.umd.js',
  defaultExtension: 'js'
},
```

or like shown in [Angular2 router-deprecated dependencies not being loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37000243/angular2-router-deprecated-dependencies-not-being-loaded/37000268#37000268)

Comment: i didn't declare this dependency in package.json, thanks mate :)